# Error in downloading/parsing XML file in R

Tags: xml, r

I tried this

```
xmlUrl <- "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"
doc <- xmlTreeParse(xmlUrl, useInternalNodes = T)
```

This code returns the following error

```
Operation timed outfailed to load external entity "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"
Error: 1: Operation timed out2: failed to load external entity "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"
```

I tried this workaround:

```
xmlUrl <- "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"
download.file(xmlUrl, "./data/w3schools.xml", method = "curl")
doc <- htmlTreeParse("./data/w3schools.xml", useInternalNodes = T)
```

It also doesn't work. It downloads some `XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </META>.` kind of error page.( When `xmlTreeParse` is used in place of `htmlTreeParse` it shows some tag mismatch error.)

Can anyone explain me where's the problem exactly in the code? Is it because of proxy network as I'm behind an authenticated proxy. But `install.packages()` runs properly, so I don't think proxy configuration is a problem here.`getURL()` also works fine.Or is there some problem in `XML` package itself?

R Version 3.0.2

Comment: The first one works for me. I am using the recent version of both R and XML package.

Comment: @user227710 I've updated the question. Can you check on your system now? Are you getting any error while using the workaround?

Comment: For the second one, you can omit `method=curl` and it works.

Comment: While you may need to use the `XML` package for various reasons, you may find working with `xml2` and `rvest` to be easier in the long run (again, depending on the work you need to do).

Answer (score 3):

You should try this instead:

```
fileUrl = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"

download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "G:/Cleaning Data/data2/food.xml")

doc = xmlTreeParse(file = "G:/Cleaning Data/data2/food.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

Comment: this answer worked for me.I dont understand why was this answer downvoted

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the XML package, there are some issues with the url arguments.
The below code works. please try it...

```
library(XML)

fileUrl <- "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"
download.file(fileUrl, destfile = "./data/simple.xml")

doc <- xmlTreeParse("./data/simple.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```